# How to use Jabber from behind a proxy allowing only ports 80 and 443?

Tags: windows, proxy, jabber

Is there a way to use Jabber (through pidgin, but could be another client) from a computer which is behind a proxy allowing only ports 80 and 443?

Comment: Ask your network admins - perhaps there is a reason the proxy blocks the ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible to use something like this (I'm not recommending it as I haven't tried it, it was the first thing that came up in Google when searching for Jabber Web Chat)

[Jabber Web Chat](http://jwchat.org/)

Since port 80 is open, this might work.